# Html css cross-platform vpn service on android and ios

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, ionic-framework, vpn

I'm trying to make an application getting my user connected to my vpn on ios and android
The problem is that after 5 hours on google, I didn't find anything.
With ionic, no one did It, no topic has an end.
With react native, the same problem.
There still is xamarin, but i'm not even sure it work because there is no working example.

If you have done an application like this, with which framework have you done a cross platform application performing a vpn connection ? Thanks